# Rxjs wait for previous interval request execution before proceeding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

**Use case:** call an endpoint every 3-minutes that would update a status of a certain service over the application.

my current code:

```html
interval(180000)
            .subscribe(() => this.doRequest
                .pipe(catchError(() => {
                    this.applicationFlag = false;
                    return EMPTY;
                }))
                .subscribe(result => this.applicationFlag = result));
```

My current problem is that sometimes the previous interval request has not been completed yet but the next interval request was also doing a request.

Is there a way to flag to wait for previous or don't execute the interval when the previous request is not completed yet?

Comment: "sometimes the previous interval request has not been completed yet" => That means your requests need 3 minutes to get answered?

Comment: does adding exhaustMap() to the pipe help? it ignores new requests as long as current requests arent finished

Comment: @OliverGebert not really, it's just a specified timeframe from a configuration form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have one `subscribe` inside another `subscribe` there's no way the outer chain can be notified that the inner chain has completed. You have to restructure your chain and use operators such as `concatMap`, `mergeMap` or `switchMap`. For example like the following:

```
interval(180000)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => this.doRequest.pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        this.applicationFlag = false;
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    ),
  )
  .subscribe();
```